# How to fix the auto update of score in pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I want to fix the auto updating of the following code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('song.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)

display_width = 800
display_height  = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('KALM Creation')


#Score
score=0

#img=pygame.image.load("1.png")
#intro=pygame.image.load("intro.png")
foodimg=pygame.image.load("food.png")

#Our Icon For The Game
icon=pygame.image.load('icon1.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

AppleThickness=30
block_size = 10
FPS = 30

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

#The score function

def scoredisplay(scoredef=0):
    text=smallfont.render("Score :%s" %(scoredef) ,True ,black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,[0,0])
#The random function of apple
def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = round(random.randrange(0, display_width-AppleThickness))
    randAppleY = round(random.randrange(0, display_height-AppleThickness))

    return randAppleX,randAppleY
randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()

#Starting Of the game
def game_intro():

    intro = True
    while intro:    
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_c:
                intro = False
            if event.key ==pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("Welcome To  Eat it Game",
                          green,
                          -200,
                          size="medium")
        message_to_screen("This Game is created by KALM Creations",
                          black,
                          -30,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Eat the food to gain a score!",
                          black,
                          10,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Avoid the rock , if you hit them you lose!",
                          black,
                          50,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Press 'C' to play the game or 'Q' to quit.",
                          black,
                          150,
                          size="small")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
#Snake aka the object which is moving (in green colour)
def snake(lead_x,lead_y,block_size):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [lead_x,lead_y,block_size,block_size])

#Text Size
def text_objects(text,color, size):
    if size=="small":
        textSurface=smallfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="medium":
        textSurface=medfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="large":
        textSurface=largefont.render(text, True ,color)


    return textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()

#Message to screen
def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0,size="small"):
    textSurf,textRect=text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2),(display_height / 2)+y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

#   The game run up
def gameLoop():
    score=0
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0

    randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()


    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:

            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              red,
                              y_displace=-50,
                              size="large")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit",
                              black,
                              y_displace=50,
                              size="medium")

            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change = block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0

        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
            gameOver = True



        gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,(randAppleX,randAppleY))

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,(randAppleX,randAppleY))

        snake(lead_x,lead_y,block_size)
        scoredisplay()
        pygame.display.update()



        if lead_x > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleY + AppleThickness or lead_x + block_size>randAppleX and lead_x + block_size< randAppleX + AppleThickness:
             if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y< randAppleY + AppleThickness or lead_y + block_size>randAppleY and lead_y + block_size< randAppleY + AppleThickness:
                 randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()
                 score+=1
                 scoredisplay(score)
             elif lead_y +block_size >randAppleY and lead_y +block_size < randAppleY:
                 randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()
                 score+=1
                 scoredisplay(score)
            '''
         Now when i run this game , the score keeps on updating.I want it to do like when the snake collides with 'foodimg',
         it should add +1 to the score.Also sometimes even if the snake does not touch the food , the food is moved to a random
         position.How do i fix this bug?
         '''
        scoredisplay(score)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
#Episode 36
```

In this the score is always under updation , i want to fix this also that when the snake doesn't collide with the food, the food sometimes move to a random position.How do i fix these two errors?Here is the 2 images used in the code.
[icon1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQXdO.jpg)
[Food](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf6YT.png)

Comment: Please include a few more details. Your code is long and mostly uncommented. Please also tell us what solutions you have already tried and what didn't work about them. For example, from a first glance it appears the score keeps increasing because your player keeps touching the object which gives them score. Did you try saving the old position and comparing it with the new to detect whether movement occured in the first place and only then update the score?

Comment: I got the solution , thanks anyway CherryDt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were calling scoredisplay() without an input at one point and calling it unnecessarily in other places. Below is amended code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('song.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)

display_width = 800
display_height  = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('KALM Creation')


#Score
score=0

#img=pygame.image.load("1.png")
#intro=pygame.image.load("intro.png")
foodimg=pygame.image.load("food.png")

#Our Icon For The Game
icon=pygame.image.load('icon1.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

AppleThickness=30
block_size = 10
FPS = 30

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

#The score function

def scoredisplay(scoredef=0):
    text=smallfont.render("Score :%s" %(scoredef) ,True ,black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,[0,0])
#The random function of apple
def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = round(random.randrange(0, display_width-AppleThickness))
    randAppleY = round(random.randrange(0, display_height-AppleThickness))

    return randAppleX,randAppleY
randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()

#Starting Of the game
def game_intro():

    intro = True
    while intro:    
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_c:
                intro = False
            if event.key ==pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("Welcome To  Eat it Game",
                          green,
                          -200,
                          size="medium")
        message_to_screen("This Game is created by KALM Creations",
                          black,
                          -30,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Eat the food to gain a score!",
                          black,
                          10,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Avoid the rock , if you hit them you lose!",
                          black,
                          50,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Press 'C' to play the game or 'Q' to quit.",
                          black,
                          150,
                          size="small")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
#Snake aka the object which is moving (in green colour)
def snake(lead_x,lead_y,block_size):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [lead_x,lead_y,block_size,block_size])

#Text Size
def text_objects(text,color, size):
    if size=="small":
        textSurface=smallfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="medium":
        textSurface=medfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="large":
        textSurface=largefont.render(text, True ,color)


    return textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()

#Message to screen
def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0,size="small"):
    textSurf,textRect=text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2),(display_height / 2)+y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

#   The game run up
def gameLoop():
    score=0
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0

    randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()


    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:

            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              red,
                              y_displace=-50,
                              size="large")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit",
                              black,
                              y_displace=50,
                              size="medium")

            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change = -block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change = block_size
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lead_y_change = -block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lead_y_change = block_size
                    lead_x_change = 0

        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
            gameOver = True



        gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,(randAppleX,randAppleY))

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,(randAppleX,randAppleY))

        snake(lead_x,lead_y,block_size)
        pygame.display.update()



        if lead_x > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleY + AppleThickness or lead_x + block_size>randAppleX and lead_x + block_size< randAppleX + AppleThickness:
             if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y< randAppleY + AppleThickness or lead_y + block_size>randAppleY and lead_y + block_size< randAppleY + AppleThickness:
                 randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()
                 score+=1
             elif lead_y +block_size >randAppleY and lead_y +block_size < randAppleY:
                 randAppleX,randAppleY=randAppleGen()
                 score+=1

        scoredisplay(score)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
#Episode 36
```

If you want to move the target if not collected, set up a timer that counts up every tick. If the counter goes above a certain number then move the target, if the player collects the target in time reset the counter.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks.Can you tell me how to add enemies in the game which follow the snake so when the snake collides with the enemy , game gets over.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do that, you'll have to work it out yourself :). One thing I recommend is learning about classes. When programs contain distinct objects like a snake(player) and enemies(AI), classes can greatly simplify code.